# What option should I use for iframe sandbox

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

I had a video that stopped being controllable when I appended a safety feature: I added
"&origin=http://mydomain.com" to the attributes of the iframe that had the video.  (By not controllable I mean that the youtube api stopped working).  So I decided to use the "sandbox" feature, which is also for security.
Unfortunately, it works too well - it blocks content too.
So if all I want to do is prevent the iframe from causing mischief, but I also want to play third party videos, should I use:
sandbox=""
or
sandbox="allow-same-origin"
I don't quite understand it from the W3schools description.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the `origin=` parameter on the URL that you include as the `src=` for your iframe tag.

One thing to try is URL escaping the `://` characters in the parameter's value, e.g. `origin=http%3A%2F%2F//mydomain.com`. Does that help? If so, we'll get [the example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds) updated to reflect the need to escape.

If that doesn't help, could you please provide the full iframe tag, including all the attributes and their values, that you're using?

Comment: This is the iframe code that fails.  I didn't really test your idea.  Anyway, the code is: '<div id="ContainPlayer" style="position:relative;">       
    <iframe id="player" width="610.666666666667" height="458" 
    src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/czK6dSRIxZs?hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1&autohide=0&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&playerapiid=ourvideoid&rel=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent&origin=http://rateforsuccess.com'
    frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    </div>'

Comment: src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/czK6dSRIxZs?hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1&autohide=0&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&playerapiid=ourvideoid&rel=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent&origin=http://rateforsuccess.com'
    frameborder="0"

Comment: I can't tell how much of this is SO automatically shortening your URL. Are you deliberately not including a URL scheme (e.g. http:// or https://) before you youtube.com, and are you putting in a semicolon after the `src='...';` for a reason?

Comment: I see that I can't add code.  there is a url scheme (http:// and there is no semicolor after src.  I'll try removing url parts here:  /embed/czK6dSRIxZs?hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=1&autohide=0&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&playerapiid=ourvideoid&rel=0&controls=1&showinfo=0&wmode=transparent&origin=http://rateforsuccess.moc'
    frameborder="0"

Comment: the url has .moc after it because I thought it might cause problems when posting to this stackoverflow comment.  normally it is .com

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going on. Could you try using the YT.Player() constructor to add the video to your page (which will also set the proper origin= attribute at the same time)? https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Comment: Do I have to explicitly set the origin attribute in the YT.Player constructor, or is it done automatically for me?  I know I have to set other attributes, but from your question I'm not sure on 'origin'.

Comment: SOLVED!!!  You found the solution to multiple problems.  One I create all of the iframe attributes in playervars, and do not use an iframe, it works.  I looked into this a little further.  This solution is necessary for aspx pages, but is not necessary for htm pages.  Also, even with the solution, google Chrome has problems painting the area of the video (unless you shift to another tab and then come back.  AGAIN, this is an asp.net issue!  It works fine with html pages.  To see what I'm talking about, look at the following 4 pages:

Comment: testie.aspx, testie.htm, testchrome.aspx, testchrome.htm (testie has the iframes, testchrome does not, so the names are a bit misleading).  the asp page should be identical to the htm page, though by translation there are a few differences.

Comment: One other point.  To duplicate the error consistently, you need to clear the cache (in IE you use CTRL-R, and I also do Tools/Internet Options/Delete, though I have not checked if this is needed) and then  close the browser, open it again, and use it on the page you are testing.  clicking the radio should pause the video (and give an alert) if it works.

Answer (score -1):

origin only works on  html pages, not on asp.net pages.  I tested it.